# Alternative of CreateVideoSource() in webrtc

Tags: c++, webrtc, chromium

Hi all I had seen one webrtc old source code which has this method called CreateVideoSource() for adding streams after an CreateAudioTrack() call.

```
rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::VideoTrackSourceInterface> video_source =
        peer_connection_factory_->CreateVideoSource(std::unique_ptr<cricket::VideoCapturer>(
            media_source->GetVideoCapturer()),
            NULL);
```

What's happening is whenever I try to build it gives an error for the above CreateVideoSource() that it is undefined. And the reason behind that is the latest webrtc-checkout has deprecated this.
So my question is, I wanted to know the alternative which they have introduced after deprecating this method. So can anyone tell me what the alternate approach is.

Comment: Looks like `CreateVideoTrack` is the API you are searching for. It's declared here: api/peer_connection_interface.h: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/master/api/peer_connection_interface.h

Comment: No, actually I'm aware of that, CreateVideoTrack() has 2 parameters and the 2nd one is the videosource, for which which this CreateVideoSource() is used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Finally I was able to come up with an alternative(i.e the current implementation of libwebrtc) after looking into bundle examples and tests.

[Line 71 is a good point to start](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/webrtc/examples/peerconnection/client/conductor.cc?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F)

Comment: Are you using custom capturer? How did you manage to adapt the capturer to CapturerTrackSource? Can you show some code? @vishal